# Subsubsection label -- alphabetical

Tags: sectioning, numbering, labels

I'm working with a thesis template and trying to change the subsection to alphabetical style, while leaving the chapter section headings as numerals (i.e. 1.1.A).

After looking at other questions on StackExchange, the common solution to the problem seemed to be solely including the code below in the thesis preamble document. But for some reason, this is not working for me.

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection\alph{subsection}}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close!

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Alph{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for the correction! For some reason in my thesis it doesn't work -- not sure why it doesn't override the template!

Comment: @jrjrjr Could you copy the document and try to keep removing parts of it to get an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/) that still doesn't produce the desired result but is small enough that you can add the code to your question as an edit?

Comment: Would this help? This is the template I am using https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-for-cambridge-university-engineering-department-cued-latex-xelatex-and-lualatex-support-v2-dot-1/kgfqybfnqkdf

Comment: @jrjrjr Yes, it does! Changing `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` (assuming you also want the subsubsections appearing in the table of contents) in the `preamble.tex` file (currently on lines 142 and 143, respectively) with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` instead of what the template set should do the trick; see e.g. https://latexref.xyz/Sectioning.html#Sectioning for some more info.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! Really appreciate it. Unfortunately still not working! Added the \renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Alph{subsubsection}}
line right after the secnumdepth and tocdepth

Comment: @jrjrjr In that case, maybe it's not the `\thesubsubsection` you want to redefine, but rather the `\thesubsection`? If you leave the `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` lines as they were and put `\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}` after them instead, does that give you the desired output?

Comment: that worked, thank you!